# Images are not loading from aws

Tags: php, amazon-web-services

I want to display images in image tag from amazon s3

```
<img alt="" class="pictureWidth" src="https://xyz.s3.amazonaws.com/images/estimates/1_6.jpg">
```

I checked that image have there in the location and it has permission and also I run that url in the browser it shows as follows

```
images/estimates/1_6.jpg
```

Following the sample code for uploading the images

```
$result = $s3->putObject(array(
            'Bucket'       => $s3bucketName,
            'Key'          => $fileName,
            'Body'         => $fileName,
            'ContentType'  => 'text/plain',
            'ACL'          => 'public-read',
            'StorageClass' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY',
       ));
```

I also tried with 'ContentType'  => 'image/jpeg', but no luck

```
https://servicefusion.s3.amazonaws.com/images/estimates/7.jpg
```

What is the issue ?

Comment: show us the code for uploading images

Comment: @Viscocent I edited with uploaded code..

Comment: `'ContentType'  => 'text/plain',` - theres the issue

Comment: switch to `image/jpeg` or `image/png`

Comment: `image/jpeg` not `images/jpeg`, im sorry my first answer was wrong.

Comment: what kind of images are you uploading? png?

Comment: What exactly is in the `$fileName` variable?

Comment: @Jack op says the images are uploaded correctly, but not displayed right when accessed on the browser.

Comment: @Viscocent Yeah, that would happen if you upload text contents instead of an image ;-)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
   $result = $s3->putObject(array(
        'Bucket'       => $s3bucketName,
        'Key'          => $fileName,
        'Body'         => $fileName,
        'ContentType'  => 'image/jpeg',
        'ACL'          => 'public-read',
        'StorageClass' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY',
   ));
```

**update**
just updated that was `image/jpeg` not `images/jpeg`

for other kinds of filetypes go here for reference:
http://www.utoronto.ca/web/htmldocs/book/book-3ed/appb/mimetype.html

if that was not your problem then refer to:

http://s3browser.com/features-content-mime-types-editor.php

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `'Body'` but instead use `'SourceFile'`, otherwise you will upload a file with the filename as its contents.

```
$result = $s3->putObject(array(
    'Bucket'       => $s3bucketName,
    'Key'          => $fileName,
    'SourceFile'   => $fileName,
    'ContentType'  => 'image/jpeg',
    'ACL'          => 'public-read',
    'StorageClass' => 'REDUCED_REDUNDANCY',
));
```

See also: [`putObject`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_putObject)